# Bot Framework (.Net) - Hero Card button click - IAwaitable with a custom type

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I have a class (let's say *XYZ*) and I'm passing a list of type *XYZ* to a Hero Card as buttons, so that when user clicks on a button, it returns the clicked item's value. I have a method called *getResult* which expects a value of type *XYZ*.

`private async Task getResult(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<XYZ> result)`{}

The above method is executed from`context.Wait<XYZ>(getResult);`

But when I click on a button, an error occurs (`InvalidTypeException: invalid type: expected Microsoft.MscaBot.Data.XYZ, have Activity`).

How can I avoid this error and receive the item clicked by the user?

**Update**: (Following is what my code looks like)

```
[Serializable]
public class XYZ
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
}
```

Other class:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private static List<XYZ> listOfXYZ = new List<XYZ>() { new XYZ() { name = "MyName1", price = 20.23 }, new XYZ() { name = "MyName2", price = 50.63 } };

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await ShowOptions (context);
    }

    private async Task ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var replyToConversation = context.MakeMessage();
        replyToConversation.Type = "message";


        List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
        foreach (var item in listOfXYZ)
        {
            CardAction CardButton = new CardAction()
            {
               Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
               Title = item.ToString(),
               Value = item
            };
            cardButtons.Add(CardButton);
        }

        HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
        {
            Text = "Please select one of the options below",
            Buttons = cardButtons,
        };
        Attachment myAttachment = heroCard.ToAttachment();
        replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
        replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "list";
        await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
        context.Wait(getResult);
    }

    private async Task getResult(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
         // Some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you receive correctly response to your controller - could you post json-serialized 'Activity' sample to demonstrate what you are receiving? Something like "{ "type": "message","id": "1ffg ... "

Comment: When I serialize the result, I get an empty json output...

Comment: You can do that. The hero card post an activity, not your object.. the activity will contain your object string representation as part of the text value.

Comment: @Curiousity - "empty json output.." - then you serialized probably something else - if you serialize actvity from following fragment "public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)" then you allways get something..

Comment: I meant that you **can't** do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CardAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/ConnectorAPI/Models/CardAction.cs) of the `HeroCard` (or any other card) will end up posting an `IMessageActivity` to the bot. The Text of that activity will be the Value you set in the `CardAction`.

What you are trying to do is not possible. You need to await an `IMessageActivity`. If you are trying to send a complex object as the value, make sure the object it's serializable otherwise it won't work either.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm trying to send an object of class _XYZ_ as the `Value`. And that class is serializable. And I changed the await to `IMessageActivity` like you said. But when I click on a button (there are 3 other buttons in the same Card), nothing happens now. Not even an Exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know :) show some code and we might be able to help

Comment: Hi @Ezequiel :) I updated my question with my code. The getResult method is not called when I debug.

Comment: I made the button Type as PostBack, so that I can debug. But the activity returning to the Controller is null. What can be the reason for the activity to be null?

Comment: You need to serialize item and use that as the value of the CardAction. You cannot use item as the value

Comment: But the classes are already marked as `Serializable`. Do I have to serialize each and every object before assigning to the `value` of the `CardAction`? Can you please give me sample code to show what you mean?

Comment: I would try that to see if that works or not to isolate the problem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: Serializing each object when assigning to Value does it. Thank you for your comments and the answer :)